# Why does my desktop freeze when SSH password prompt goes out of focus?

Tags: ssh, x-windows

I use tmux in a fullscreened terminal emulator. Sometimes when I use SSH the password prompt goes out of focus and disappears "behind" the terminal emulator, and X (*I think*) freezes *whenever this happens*. I can't ALT+TAB to retrieve the prompt, nor can I switch to a different workspace. But my system isn't frozen when this happens; I can switch to a virtual console, and all my processes keep going as though nothing happened (Spotify kept playing as if nothing had happened).

I use Ubuntu 14.04, and OpenSSH 6.6.1p1.

Comment: In X, a window can grab focus in such a way that switching away from it is blocked, which would be bad news if the window is not on top. It looks like Ubuntu 14.04 uses gnome-keyring-daemon with the seahorse front end for ssh passwords. Maybe try to disable those so that you type ssh passwords directly in the terminal.